# Restricting time intervals in DateTime Picker

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I'm using [this](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) to select date and time. The documentation does not mention about time picker, but it works anyhow.

HTML:

```
<div class="dateTimePicker">
        <input name="start" type="text" value="">
        <span class="add-on"><i class="time-icon"></i></span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".dateTimePicker").datetimepicker({
    pickDate: false,
    pickTime: true,
    useSeconds: false,
    format: 'hh:mm'
});
```

This works all fine. It shows a selector with intervals of `1 hour for hours, 3 minutes for minutes and 3 seconds for seconds.`

My aim is to change the intervals of minutes from 3 to 15. Currently, the selector for minutes shows: `00 03 06 etc`. Can I change it to `00 15 30 45`. Is this even possible or are there any other time pickers which give me this flexibility?

Comment: take a look towards this jQuery plugin  this may solve your query http://www.jqueryrain.com/?ixXmZ27b

Answer (score 9):

```
$(".dateTimePicker").datetimepicker({
    step: 15 
});
```

> This is how sets interval in jquery datetimepicker

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).

Answer (score 7):

You need to use stepping, this page explains it all, http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#stepping

```
$(".dateTimePicker").datetimepicker({
    pickDate: false,
    pickTime: true,
    useSeconds: false,
    format: 'hh:mm',
    stepping: 15 //will change increments to 15m, default is 1m
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".dateTimePicker").datetimepicker({
  .
  .
  "stepMinute" : 5 //Will Change Minute Interval as 00, 05, 10 ... 55
  .
  .
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this For Interval in [The Kendo UI TimePicker](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/timepicker/overview#define-the-interval-in-minutes-between-values-in-the-list)

```
<input id="timePicker" />
<script>
   $("#timePicker").kendoTimePicker({
      interval: 15
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for a bootstrap compliant timepicker library, I would suggest the [bootstrap-timepicker](http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker) library which supports the time range and stepping features.

A sample would be based on your source code:

```js
$(".dateTimePicker").timepicker({({
  secondStep: 30, // "minuteStep" is also an alternative option 
  showSeconds: true
});
```

Comment: hi, you said it supports time range, can you tell me how do i do that, i need to restrict past time to be able to selected.