# jquery-simple-datetimepicker change time interval based on current time and date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquerydatetimepicker

I am using ([jquery-simple-datetimepicker](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Date-Time-Picke-Plugin-Simple-Datetimepicker/)) for a small restaurant application. the restaurant timing is from 6 am to 12 am. My issue is the time interval starts from 00:00 to 23:30 in the dropdown but, it should show the time interval of 1 hour.
for example, if the current time is 10 am the interval should start from after 6 hours that is `4:00, 5:00` till `12:00 am`. and if the time is `7: pm` or after then it should show time for next day that is `6:00,7:00` till `12: am`.
will I able to achieve in this plugin or do you prefer any other customizable plugins?

here is my code

```js
$('#datetimepicker2').appendDtpicker({
  todayButton: true,
  step: 60,
  closeOnSelected: true,
  minuteInterval: 30,
  onSelect: function() {},

  onInit: function(handler) {
    var picker = handler.getPicker();

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Date-Time-Picke-Plugin-Simple-Datetimepicker/jquery.simple-dtpicker.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Date-Time-Picke-Plugin-Simple-Datetimepicker/jquery.simple-dtpicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
<input type="text" name="date9" id="datetimepicker2">
```

can anyone help me out, please?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971015/restricting-time-intervals-in-datetime-picker ?

Answer (score 0):

Try minuteInterval 60?

```
$('#datetimepicker2').appendDtpicker({
  todayButton: true,
  step: 60,
  closeOnSelected: true,
  minuteInterval: 60,
  minTime: "06:00",
  maxTime: "23:59",
  onSelect: function() {},

  onInit: function(handler) {
    var picker = handler.getPicker();

  }
});
```

Comment: minuteInterval: 60, still shows 30 minutes interval. how can I show the time interval based on the current time. for example, i want to add 6 hours to current time if the time 10 am then I want to show the interval from `4:00 5:00`, etc till `12:00`.

Comment: could you help me please?

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation](https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/jQuery-Date-Time-Picke-Plugin-Simple-Datetimepicker.html). You need to set the `current` property to the new date-time.

Comment: `current: new Date()`, I have added this, but no changes.

Comment: As you said so yourself: you need to add 6 hours to the current time. Then apply it to the date picker like you did just now.

Comment: `var d1 = new Date ();
var d2 = new Date ( d1 );
d2.setHours ( d1.getHours() + 6 )   current: d2,`

Comment: It doesn't change anything, we have to add 6 hours to minTime instead of current?

Comment: and also I want to change the time on change date event so, how can I fire event on change of date?